# how to get data from twitter using twitter api-rest

Tags: java, android, api, twitter

Hello I've been "stuck" with a problem for a long time and I can't find a solution. It turns out that I'm developing an android app in java, the app must have a button that allows me to enter the app's user profile through my twitter account , the profile should show my twitter username, email and profile picture. So far I have not been successful in being able to log in from my twitter account, I have used different libraries (the last one was twitter kit 3.1.1) but nothing :(, I'm already so desperate that I'm thinking of getting the data directly from the twitter api but I don't know how since the documentation is not very clear to me (I'm a newbie in programming). How to get the aforementioned information from the twitter api or from a library (although I think they are outdated and that is why they do not work). Thank you for taking the time to read my problem

Comment: May be api key required for twitter api. If endpoints not deprecated, you should get access authorization to Twitter API with API key.

Comment: What do you mean by an API key for the Twitter API? Are they the keys that are generated when registering the app on twitter (consumer keys, brearer token, acces token and secret)? Sorry, but as I said before I am a newbie in the programming and how do I get the twitter endpoints

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.